# Shape signature of an object in python?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision

How to calculate the shape signature of an object from a binary image in python? I am not getting an function to calculate the perimeters of the binary object.

Comment: I have used regionprop of skimage. But the perimieter property giving me  a scalar valued output. Not getting what is it. :(

Comment: But the perimeter is a scalar value? What else should the function return?  I don't get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a look at that skimage library.

In case you are looking for your blob's contour (I assume you just confused that with perimeter) to calculate things like centroid distance functions you might give skimage.measure.find_contours(array, level) a try. It looks like what you need.

Perimeter is the length of that contour which of course is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Shape Indexes", which are values describing the shape, thus they can be considered as shape signature. Moments for example are shape indexes. Sometimes they are good enough to solve your problem.

[Take a look here](http://www.thibault.biz/Doc/Publications/ShapeAndTextureIndexesIJPRAI2013.pdf), you have a list of shape indexes. I strongly advise to avoid shape indexes using the perimeter, because it is a very unstable measure.